# plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, build.gradle

I have been trying to set up Firebase on my app, but have run into a wall.

=== The error is below ===

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Andre\FlutterDart\flutter_app_1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 5
- What went wrong:
  Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.4.0', apply: false]

> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

========

By 2 gradle files are as follows:

android>app>build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version '4.4.0' apply false
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}



android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_app_1"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_app_1"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

android>build.grade

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong since I'm just following the instructions provided by firebase.

I tried removing one of them and see if it works. Removing any of the 'com.google.gms.google-services' only broke it more. I tried removing the version from either of them to see if only 1 needed the version but nope. Ran out of ideas there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried messing around with it a bit more. This removed the error but still didn't make it work. At least 1 hurdle has been taken care off XD

```
id "com.google.gms.google-services" apply false
```

I removed the version which made it stop failing to launch.

Finally got it to work. Needed to install nodejs.org/en/
Reason: No idea.

Then, I needed to install flutterfire_cli.
This needed quite a bit of work but I managed. It is finally working.